# Spring boot batch insert, rollback as groups

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So i'm working on a spring boot project and i need to insert some bulk data. But i want to insert it as groups like say 20 entities per group and if something goes wrong i want it to rollback the group not the whole thing. How can i achive that?

Here is what i have in mind:

```
@Transactional
public void saveBatchAsGroups(List<EntityClass> data) {
    List<EntityClass> group = new ArrayList();
    for (EntityClass entity : data) {
        //some operations

        group.add(entity);
        if (group.size() > 19) {
            saveGroup(group);
            group.clear();
        }
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveGroup(List<EntityClass> group) {
    someRepository.saveAll(group);
}
```

This way `saveGroup` opens a new transaction for every save operation.

Is this a good practice in terms of performance etc., can it done without a bunch of new transactions like with save points or something like that? what is the best way to achive this kind of job?

Comment: if I’m not wrong you can define the `commit-interval` in the step

Comment: In Java configuration you can configure the chunk in the step. chunk: The Java-specific name of the dependency that indicates that this is an item-based step and the number of items to be processed before the transaction is committed.

Comment: And you don’t need to take care of the list just implement `ItemWriter`

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't now stacked transactions, so the outer `@Transactional` is at least confusing.

Other than that this looks ok.
You might want to consider Spring Batch though, which is build for this kind of process.